# How to get the adress of a C++ attribute from Windbg by script

Tags: c++, windbg

How can I get the address of an attribute of an instance in Windbg using a script file?

An attribute change unexpectedly and can't see from there the value is changed from the Visual Studio 2010 debugger and using a break point om the memory address doe snot help since I cannot unset the break point after the destructor of the class was called. The specific instance of the of the object where the error occur is also not fixed.

This is a user space application.

Comment: There is no attributes in C++ proper. C++/CX does have attributes, but apparently it is not what you are talking about, since your "attributes" change, while C++/CX attributes are immutable. Please clarify what you are talking about. Perhaps you mean a member field?

Comment: With attributes I mean die member fields. From a google search I see that attributes have a different meaning as I have used it above.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct, you need to set a ba (Break on Access), on the
Address + offset of a C++ class instance.
This is possible as long as the class in question not is instantiated a lot of times.

1) Create an ordinary bp break in the constructor after the the attribute is initialized.

```
bp Foo:Foo+<xxx>
```

You must figure out the offset of the attribute, Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309970/get-sizeof-type-in-windbg/8311961#8311961) .

You must figure which register holds the this pointer at this moment.

2) Then modify the 1) break to set an additional   ba (Break on Access)

The break address must then be calculated to the this + offset.
It is important the ID is specified because we must delete the break in destructor

It should be something like:

```
bp <module>!Foo:Foo+<xxx> “ba[@eax] w4 @eax+4;gc ”
From hlp:
[~Thread] ba[ID] Access Size [Options] [Address [Passes]] ["CommandString"]
```

3) Set a code break (bp) in the destructor, and remove the ba from above
Again ypu must find a register which directly or indirectly holds the this pointer.
Something like:

```
bc[poi(@ebp-0x08)]
```

I have done this, it works as long as you don’t run out of breakpoints if the program instantiate too many.

NB: the syntax may not be 100% correct, it’s some time since last time.

Comment: You understood the question correct. Does there exist some C++ to CPU mapping I should known about when using Windbg? Like from where do I get the value of the this pointer?

Comment: The value of the this pointer is returned from the heap manager, The "!heap -a" will list all entries, but it can't be called a mapping to C++.

Comment: "!heap -a" complain about wow64!_TEB64 (I am not using the correct symbols), I have a Windows 7 64 bit machine and did install the symbols for 64 and 32 bit. The PC does not have direct access to the internet so cannot use the symbol server in Windbg. Which symbol must I use?